# passing parameters in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am creating crytal report from a stored procedure ,this works fine when i pass one parameter but it shows an error

> "incorrect parameter "

when i pass two parameters 
my code is

```
 {
    ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    paramField.Name = "@Dept";
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    paramFields.Add(paramField);

    paramField.Name = "@Name";
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    paramFields.Add(paramField);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
    reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa", "OPWFMS-7KYGZ7SB", "test");

}
```

please let me know any changes

Comment: Just for your information, vowels are free here.

Answer (score 9):

You need to create new parameterField and value for both parameters. Your current code adds parameter, modifies it (change name and value) and adds same object again. This should be correct:

```
 {
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
// ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField.Name = "@Dept";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

paramField = new ParameterField(); // <-- This line is added
paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  // <-- This line is added
paramField.Name = "@Name";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa", "OPWFMS-7KYGZ7SB", "test");
```

}

**EDIT:**
Error mentioned in comment is probably because there are two definitions of variable paramField or paramDiscreteValue in code. In one c# method you can't define variable with same name more than one time. 
Try code above as it is written and if you are still getting compiler error, please paste here full error text.

Comment: no its not working 
there is error that 
paramField
paramDiscreteValue

are already defined

Comment: Yup. There are two definitions of ParameterDiscreteValue. I'll comment extra line.

Comment: This is not same error as before? 
In which line? Please post full error text.
Is this compiler or runtime error?

Comment: this is not complile time error 
report is generating but in report there is written "in correct parameter"

Comment: Then you should check if parameter names in code (@Dept and @Name) are the same as parameter names in Crystal report. Also check types - both parameters in code are strings, see that report also expects string values.

Comment: i hav lot of times 
the report is generating for one parameter there is no problem
anyway thanks for help

Comment: hi i m realy sorry
whn i add nre parameter in my code ,i thought it would directly add in report but it wasnt there 
now everythng is fine 
sorry agn

Comment: can you please help me i have same issue i cannot run crystal report when i pass parameters the crystal reports not show any thing blank screen appeared , this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095828/why-the-crystal-report-not-appear-and-no-show

Comment: i used your solution exactly as it is but when i click print button its not show the report only blank page?? please i need your help

Answer (score 5):

Try this it is a little more concise

```
{    
  ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

  reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
  reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Dept", TextBox1.Text.ToString());    
  reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text.ToString());

 // CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

  reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa", "OPWFMS-7KYGZ7SB", "test");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the actual data being passed in the parameters isn't being implicitly converted to the wrong data type.  Like if you're passing a numeric ID for the @Dept parameter, make sure the data type of the input parameter that expects to receive the value is also a numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the ParameterField before each parameter that you add to the report:

```
paramField = new ParameterField();
paramDiscreteValue.Value = ...
...
```

Comment: no its not working 
there is error that 
paramField
and 
paramDiscreteValue

are already defined

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be replicated with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005. The workaround fix is to set the ReportSource properpty of the CrystalReportViewer first, then you set the parameter values. Thus, your code should be:

```
{
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;

ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

paramField.Name = "@Dept";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

paramField.Name = "@Name";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa", "OPWFMS-7KYGZ7SB", "test");
}
```