# C# Crystal Reports - Print Selected Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report, selected

I'm working in visual studio 2010 and have included a crystal report in the project. The report includes all products owned by a client. The problem is that there are thousands of clients and I need to print a selected clients information through code. I have tried printing page numbers matching the id of the client, but some clients have more than one page of products, which causes a printout of page... say 100 for the client with an id of 100, but that page might be for client 91 since some reports for prior clients are multiple pages. My question is how would I go about printing a page for a specific client? I have been working on this for days and can't find anything helpful on the internet.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: show us the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me by your question that you are returning all of the data and then trying to filter it by code. The easier way  - in terms of programming and server load - is to filter the data on the server and only return what you need.

To do this use parameters in your reports. You can use the ClientID field as a paramter in the report. You then pass that value into your report from your code. You can then create a PDF of your report to display to your users. I use this method all the time and it works great.

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006873/passing-parameters-in-crystal-report) to get you started. Look at the last answer for the more precise option.