# How to stop Crystal Reports from prompting for parameters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using 2 stored procedures with 2 parameters for a crystal report. I have a form with 2 textboxes. I enter the parameters into the textboxes but when the report loads it still prompts the user to enter the parameters again.
Below is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub PrintReceipt()
    Dim conn_String As String
    conn_String = "Connection String"
    Dim Mycon = New SqlConnection(conn_String)
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("GetReceiptByReceiptNo", Mycon)
    Dim cmd1 = New SqlCommand("GetReceiptedItems", Mycon)
    Dim dAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dAdapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)

    dAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    dAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    dAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ReceiptNo", TxtReceiptNo.Text)
    dAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceNo", TxtInvoiceNo.Text)
    Dim dTable As New DataTable
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable)

    Dim rdc = New ReportDocument()
    rdc.Load("C:\ClientsReceipts.rpt")
    rdc.SetDataSource(dTable)
    ClientReceiptsViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdc
    ClientReceiptsViewer.Show()

End Sub
```

[image: Form where user enters parameters]
[image: Crystal report parameter prompt]

I want to Eliminate the prompt in the second image, any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to set rdc parameters as well?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Read here for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589021/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006873/passing-parameters-in-crystal-report - although I can't be sure that this applies to your case.

Comment: Edit: setting rdc parameters solved the issue