# Passing parameters in crystal report in C# is not working

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I use this code:

```
 ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        string rpt;

        rpt = "Report1.rpt";
        string reportFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string reportPath = Path.Combine(reportFolder, rpt);

        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
      
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@product_id", 11007);

        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

But every time ask me to enter parameter!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to this post, [passing parameters in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006873/passing-parameters-in-crystal-report), you could try creating a `ParameterField` and pass the value to that as a `ParameterDiscreteValue`.

Comment: You could also try passing the value as a string using ToString();